# How to Configure Forms Authentication for a Folder of my Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, forms-authentication

I have an asp.net application with a web.config file in the root and uses Windows authentication by default.

I have an Admin folder that should have Forms authentication. for this, I have added a new web.config file in the Admin folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >      
      <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" >
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>   
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now when I run a page inside the Admin folder, it gives me the below error:

```
Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

How to Configure Forms Authentication for the pages inside the Admin folder only and leaving other pages for the Windows authentication which is the default?

thanks

Comment: are you sure admin is an application and not a virtual folder?

Comment: you mean about IIS settings? Admin is not an application nor is a virtual folder. It's just a normal folder inside the root application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this you will need to do something like

In your Admin folder `web.config`

```
  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

In your root `web.config`

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```

Anyway this might help you [Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

Comment: thanks; should this be written in the root web.config or the web.config which is inside the Admin folder? I almost tried both but didn't work.

Comment: this shoud be in your Admin folder.    <authentication mode="Forms"> section should be in root

Comment: not sure what you mean; could you edit your answer what settings should be in which web.config?

Comment: hmm, only the Admin folder should use the Forms authentication. all the rest, should use Windows authentication which is the default setting. but your code makes everything use Forms authentication. Pleaser re-read the question.

Comment: Maybe only one authentication mode can be used in an asp.net application?